# Should we unregister Flow collection in Fragment/Activity?

Tags: android-lifecycle, coroutine

In the Android official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#livedata), it says the following about `StateFlow` vs `Livedata`:

> LiveData.observe() automatically unregisters the consumer when the view goes to the STOPPED state, whereas collecting from a StateFlow or any other flow does not.

and they recommend to cancel eacy flow collection like this:

```kotlin
// Coroutine listening for UI states
    private var uiStateJob: Job? = null

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Start collecting when the View is visible
        uiStateJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            latestNewsViewModel.uiState.collect { uiState -> ... }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        // Stop collecting when the View goes to the background
        uiStateJob?.cancel()
        super.onStop()
    }
```

As far as I know about structured concurrency, when we cancel the parent job, all children jobs are cancelled automatically and flow terminal operator `collect` should not be an exception. In this case, we are using `lifecycleScope` that should cancel when the lifecycleOwner is destroyed. Then, why do we need to manually cancel flow collection in this case? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When using `lifecycleScope` you do not need to cancel the jobs or scope yourself, as this scope is bound to the LifecycleOwner's lifecycle and gets cancelled when the lifecycle is detroyed. The flow is then cancelled too.

It changes as soon you are using your own CoroutineScope:

```kotlin
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

override fun onCreate() {
  // ...
  coroutineScope.launch {
    latestNewsViewModel.uiState.collect { uiState -> ... }
  }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
  // ...
  coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
}
```

In that case you would need to take care of cancelling the scope (or job's) yourself.

Comment: Well, I would say it is not complete. They might have a different use case where they wanna start in `onStart()` and stop in `onStop()`. Using lifecycleScop the observation of the flow would stop when the lifecycle reaches DESTROY state. So your question is absolutely valid.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is particular use case when we want to unregister on `onStop()` and i guess they wanna say so in the documentation because maybe the ui will crash if they get an update from the `StateFlow` while the view is in the background. In that case, lifecycleScope won't save it.

Answer (score 1):

According to @ChristianB response, we don't need to cancel coroutines that are attached to a lifecycle. the `collect()` is running inside a coroutine and will cancel too, when coroutines cancels.

> Then, why do we need to manually cancel flow collection in this case?
> what am I missing here?

When we want to use coroutines with a custom lifecycle (not using fragment/activity lifecycle). For example, I've created a helper class that needed to do sth inside itself. It launches a coroutine and it was managing (cancel/join...) its job.